# Parsing CSV File when header fields separated by Space

Tags: python, gis

I have a code below that I use to get the lat and long values from a textfile when the header fields are separated by comma. But recently I had an instance where the header fields were separated by SPACE instead of comma. So when I ran this script below, it gave me an error. I am wondering if anyone knows how I can modify the script below so the header fields that are separated by SPACE can be parsed out.

```
inFile = "file Path"

gps_track = open(inFile, 'r')

csvReader = csv.reader(log)
header = csvReader.next()

latIndex = header.index("lat")
longIndex = header.index("long")

coordlist = []

for row in csvReader:

    lat = row[latIndex]
    long = row[longIndex]
    coordlist.append([lat,long])

print coordlist
```

Comment: [Have you RTFM?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

`csv.reader` can take a delimiter as a parameter:
So you could simply fix this by using `csv.reader(log, delimiter=' ')`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't made clear if you want both delimiters to be in use. But in order to get values seperated with whitespace you should change this line:

```
csvReader = csv.reader(log)
```

to

```
csvReader = csv.reader(log, delimiter=' ')
```